# how to change the radius of the circle of GeolocationMarker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm trying to change the radius of the circle of the GeolocationMarker library to 3 km; here is my attempt:

```
var geoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();

geoMarker.setCircleOptions({radius: 3000});

geoMarker.setMap(map);
```

But it doesn't change the radius of the circle, that is the radius isn't at 3 km. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: What is GeoLocationMarker?

Comment: this one: [GeolocationMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/docs/reference.html)

Comment: Define `doesn't work`: you get a JS error, the map doesn't appear, the circle doesn't appear, the radius isn't 3km, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done like this, the documentation you link to states:

> setCircleOptions(options:google.maps.CircleOptions)       This method will
>   ignore certain properties of the google.maps.CircleOptions object. **It
>   will ignore position, radius and map properties as these are set by
>   the library**.

The radius of the circle is the accuracy of the geolocation data. If you want a constant radius circle, create a [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) object and bind the center property to the Geolocation Marker.

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({map: yourMap, radius: 3000});
circle.bindTo("center", geoMarker, "position");
```