# How do I replace the infoWindow with a circle to plot a users location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I am using the google map example of infoWindow with HTML5 geolocation and want to add a circluar marker to the map to display the users location instead of the infoWindow text box.

I have googled but not found an answer, is this possible?

```
   var map;
function initMap(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6
  });
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.Circle({map: map});

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude,
            };

            infoWindow.setCenter(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, how big do you want the circle to be?  A circular `google.maps.Marker` or a `google.maps.Circle`?.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to highlight a user's current location in google maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175931/how-to-highlight-a-users-current-location-in-google-maps)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the radius of the circle of GeolocationMarker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740696/how-to-change-the-radius-of-the-circle-of-geolocationmarker)

Comment: I've been messing on with markers and such for hours. I want it to be a maps.Circle. I'm not bothered about the size of the minute, can play with that later. Just want the working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`google.maps.Circle`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Circle) doesn't have a `.setPosition` method, it has a `.setCenter` and  `.setRadius` methods (although both or either can be set in the constructor.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvaxmaqv/1/)

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    zoom: 6
  });
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 20000
  });

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      };

      map.setCenter(pos);
      circle.setCenter(pos);
      circle.setRadius(20000);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, circle, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, circle, map.getCenter());
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, circle, pos) {
    circle.setCenter(pos);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I came across that example but it was the setCenter that I didn't see.